# Disappearing Email from Outlook 2007/exchange

Tags: email, email-server, exchange-2007, outlook-2007, iphone

Email setup and working on Secretaries PC 
boss now wants it on his iphone and his PC
set it all up as per normal ie it’s a hotmail email 
that was configured in exchange by his ex accountant.

It pops up briefly in the inbox of the bosses devices 
and then literally disappears. I’ve tried from scratch setups 
on PST and OST data files, auto archive etc.

Hair pulling aside any clues both run Outlook 2007 fully patched 
and legal. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the most common reason for emails vanishing in the manner you describe is the mixed use of email client protocols. The 2 most common protocols are POP and IMAP (The MS Exchange protocols are very IMAP like)

Without more details on how the Secretary or Boss clients are configured, I would make the assumption that the secretary is using a POP-like protocol to collect email, and the boss is using an IMAP or exchange-like protocol.

- POP is designed to collect, and then remove emails from a mail server. It is not *designed* for access from multiple clients.
- IMAP is designed to either read emails from the server, or operate on a cached copy, but the email is left on the server so it can be accessed in multiple places.

So the boss will see a new email up until the point the secretary's system grabs and deletes the server copy.

If the above is correct, then possible solutions would be:

- (best) Migrate the secretary to use IMAP/Exchange protocols to collect email.
- POP can be set to leave emails on a server. This is not ideal, but may be sufficient.

NOTE: Please forgive the assumptions I've had to make in this answer. I would have added a comment requesting more info but I have insufficient reputation

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the secretaries is configured via exchange imap no pop is used including the iphone I will say though the it’s saving to a pst on her pc.

Comment: Perhaps a setting on the secretary's mail client that tells it to transfer the mail to a local PST? Basically behaving like POP even without it? I have seen this before in very old MS mail clients, but not for 20 years!

Comment: I see please have you any idea as to how I would rectify that, I’ve tried putting them on ost but to no avail.

Comment: I found the following for Outlook 2010, it may help:

    To fix In Outlook 2010:
    Open Outlook.
    Click on the File tab.
    From the Account Settings choice list, choose Account Settings.
    On the Email tab, highlight your email account name.
    Click the Change button (a new window opens).
    Click the More Settings button.
    On the Advanced tab, look for "Leave a copy of messages on the server"

Comment: Many thanks the PST / OST was the trouble maker.